# make columns unsortable in dataTables.js jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using the dataTables.js jQuery plugin.

The first column of my table is a row counter, so I don't want it be sortable by the user. The last column contains some action link that the user can perform on a row.  How can I make these two columns unsortable?

Note: I am using pipeline (server-side process) mode of datatables.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? If yes, can you provide the right answer?

Answer (score 12):

This is done by setting [bSortable](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns) to false:

```
/* Using aoColumnDefs */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumnDefs": [ 
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
        ] } );
} );

/* Using aoColumns */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [ 
            { "bSortable": false },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        ] } );
} );
```

Answer (score 8):

DataTables 1.10+ also [supports HTML5 `data-` style attributes](https://www.datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#HTML-5), including `data-sortable="false"`, which makes the column ineligible for sorting:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-sortable="false">Row</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Join Date</th>
            <th>Organization</th>
            <th data-sortable="false">Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            [etc]
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[See this **demo in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/ptr63fxt/)

Answer (score 3):

**aaSortingFixed**

> This parameter is basically identical
>   to the aaSorting parameter, but cannot
>   be overridden by user interaction with
>   the table. What this means is that you
>   could have a column (visible or
>   hidden) which the sorting will always
>   be forced on first - any sorting after
>   that (from the user) will then be
>   performed as required. This can be
>   useful for grouping rows together.

Example of usage:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
         "aaSortingFixed": [[0,'asc'],[5,'asc']]
    } );
} );
```

`0` is number of your 'unsortable' row (from left). (So in that example the first and the sixths column are fixed)

[Official Documentation](http://www.datatables.net/usage/options#aaSortingFixed)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a callback function for support unchangeable numbers order in separate column:

```
$('#someId').dataTable({
        // ...
        "aoColumns": [
            // ...
            {"bSortable": false}, // set unsortable this column
            // ...
        ],
        fnDrawCallback: function(oSettings) {
            $(this).find('tbody tr').each(function(index) {
                $(this).find('td').eq(1).text(index + 1); // .eq([index of column])
            });
        }
    });
```